# Is there really no RatingBar in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I need to add UI that will let a user thumb over a star rating bar and set a rating. So far, I haven't found a single custom rating bar that does this.  There are plenty of non-interactive ones, but I can't use those.

I can't believe this is missing from Jetpack Compose.

Comment: Plenty of third-party options exist, including https://github.com/pseudoankit/RatingBarCompose and https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Compose-RatingBar.

Comment: I created a library with basic gesture functionality https://github.com/a914-gowtham/compose-ratingbar

Answer (score 2):

Here My RatingBar:

```
@Composable
fun RatingBar(
    rating: Float,
    maxRating: Int = 5,
    onRatingChanged: (Float) -> Unit
) {
    Row {
        for (i in 1..maxRating) {
            IconButton(onClick = { onRatingChanged(i.toFloat()) }) {
                if (i <= rating) Icons.Default.Star else Icons.Default.StarBorder
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When you call it:

```
var rating by remember { mutableStateOf(3.5f) }
            RatingBar(
                rating = rating,
                onRatingChanged = { newRating ->
                    rating = newRating
                },
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I doubt this would allow the user to "thumb over" the rating bar since you're using onClick.

Comment: Plus it fails WCAG 4.1.2 Name, Role, Value, violates expected behaviour with screen readers and switch controls (as compared to the Play store components and XML based apps)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version for a rating bar, that support float values in indicator state:

[image]

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.clickable
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.size
import androidx.compose.material.Icon
import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Star
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.geometry.Rect
import androidx.compose.ui.geometry.Size
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Outline
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.graphicsLayer
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.Density
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.LayoutDirection
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp

@Composable
fun RatingStar(
    rating: Float = 5f,
    maxRating: Int = 5,
    onStarClick: (Int) -> Unit,
    isIndicator: Boolean = false
) {
    Row {
        for (i in 1..maxRating) {
            if (i <= rating.toInt()) {
                // Full stars
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Default.Star,
                    contentDescription = null,
                    tint = MaterialTheme.colors.secondary,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(24.dp)
                        .clickable(!isIndicator) {
                            onStarClick(i)
                        }
                )
            } else if (i == rating.toInt() + 1 && rating % 1 != 0f) {
                // Partial star
                PartialStar(fraction = rating % 1)
            } else {
                // Empty stars
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Default.Star,
                    contentDescription = null,
                    tint = Color.Gray,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(24.dp)
                        .clickable(!isIndicator) {
                            onStarClick(i)
                        }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
@Composable
private fun PartialStar(fraction: Float) {
    val customShape = FractionalClipShape(fraction)

    Box {
        Icon(
            imageVector = Icons.Default.Star,
            contentDescription = null,
            tint = Color.Gray,
            modifier = Modifier.size(24.dp)
        )
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .graphicsLayer(
                    clip = true,
                    shape = customShape
                )
        ) {
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Default.Star,
                contentDescription = null,
                tint = MaterialTheme.colors.secondary,
                modifier = Modifier.size(24.dp)
            )
        }
    }
}


private class FractionalClipShape(private val fraction: Float) : Shape {
    override fun createOutline(
        size: Size,
        layoutDirection: LayoutDirection,
        density: Density
    ): Outline {
        return Outline.Rectangle(
            rect = Rect(
                left = 0f,
                top = 0f,
                right = size.width * fraction,
                bottom = size.height
            )
        )
    }
}
```

and this is how it should be called from compose:

```
 var rating by remember { mutableFloatStateOf(4.5f) }

    RatingStar(rating, maxRating = 5, {
        rating = it.toFloat()
    }, false)
```